# Detecting close of client connect in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am using node.js for long held connections. I want to know how I can detect when the client connection closes (maybe when the user closes the tab). How do I specify a callback for that?

Answer (score 14):

Answering my own question - You can detect close of client connection by doing:

```javascript
http.createServer(function(request, response) {    
    request.connection.addListener('close', function () {
        // callback is fired when connection closed (e.g. closing the browser)
    });
}
```

Comment: this triggers after you send a response, not before then.

Comment: @JasonS That is the connection call back... The event is added when the user connects to the server -- nothing to do with needing to send a request.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Socket.io](http://socket.io/).  It supports the following transports with fallbacks in this order:

1. WebSocket
2. Adobe Flash Socket
3. AJAX long polling
4. AJAX multipart streaming
5. Forever Iframe
6. JSONP Polling

The benefit is you'll be able to handle a lot more concurrent connections than long polling alone.  In addition you'll get a rich set of features like heartbeats and disconnects.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  // ... other socket handlers here ...

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    // do something to handle the disconnect
  });
});
```