# Detecting close of client connect in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Did some research online but not too much useful info.

I am using Django to build some long lasting connections and using SSE to return stream response to client(SSE should not matter though). I want to be able to detect when the client closed the connection (e.g. by closing their browser or abort the connection via frondend UI). Is there a way to do so in Django? I found it in node.js [Detecting close of client connect in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953568/detecting-close-of-client-connect-in-node-js) but not too much info for django.

I tried to do some local testing and seems that the pipe will be broken when the connection is closed by the client. The below log is from my django server:

```
[12/Jul/2023 05:35:59,679] - Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 61923)
```

How can I detect above in my code when I try to return a response?

Tried search online and also did some local testing. Expext someone can show me some code sample how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by creating a Django middleware and add it in your `settings.py`, we have a signal called `request_finished` in Django, just use it and check if the response is available or the request is closed like this:

```py
from django.core.signals import request_finished
from django.dispatch import receiver


class ConnectionClosedMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        self.response = None

    def __call__(self, request):
        @receiver(request_finished)
        def handle_request_finished(sender, **kwargs):
            if self.response and self.response.streaming_response.closed:
                print("Connection closed by the client")
        
        response = self.get_response(request)
        self.response = response
        return response
```

and add this middleware in your `settings.py` like this:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # Other middleware classes
    'yourapp.middleware.ConnectionClosedMiddleware',
]
```

Make sure to replace `yourapp.middleware.ConnectionClosedMiddleware` with your middleware path.